# How do I find the stack trace in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, exception, stack-trace

I ask because I couldn't find the stack trace in Visual Studio, while debugging an exception that occurred.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

**While debugging**, Go to **Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack**

Comment: The call stack in VS 2013 never shows anything useful. It would be nice for it to show the callers of the objects that throws an unhandled exception. Is there a hidden option to make it useful? Perhaps you can expand on your answer to provide examples.

Comment: Love how everyone else in other threads similar to this totally missed the MOST important part of the answer.

Comment: Nice, Thanks! This even works, while running VS CE 2015 + IE9 and debugging JavaScript stack trace of IE9!

Answer (score 141):

**While debugging**, and

**When you hit a break-point**.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

[image]

Comment: +1 for the picture =D (I like when someone put an enforce to make a screenshot)

Answer (score 40):

The default shortcut key is Ctrl-Alt-C.

Comment: It's important to note that you must be in 'debug' mode to see the call stack window.

Comment: @dss539 I think you have a debugger *attached*, it can either debug or release build.  It's also important that you have enough *symbols* loaded for your debugging session, otherwise you will get misleading/garbage callstacks.

Comment: @ChrisO -- Yes, I meant that Visual Studio should be in the 'debugging' state. Sorry, I can see how my original wording leaves room for misinterpretation.

Answer (score 16):

Do you mean finding a stack trace of *the thrown exception location*?  That's either Debug/Exceptions, or better - Ctrl-Alt-E. Set filters for the exceptions you want to break on.

There's even a way to reconstruct the thrower stack *after* the exception was caught, but it's really [unpleasant](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/01/18/355697.aspx). Much, much easier to set a break on the throw.

Answer (score 6):

Using the Call Stack Window

To open the Call Stack window in Visual Studio, from the Debug menu, choose Windows>Call Stack. To set the local context to a particular row in the stack trace display, double click the first column of the row.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439516(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Consider this as the current update (Windows 10 (Version 1803) and Visual Studio 2017):
I was unable to view the stack trace window and did find an option/menu item to view it. On investigating further, it seems this feature is not available on Windows 10. For further information please refer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/viewing-the-call-stack-in-visual-studio

Copied from the above link: 
"This feature is not available in Windows 10, version 1507 and later versions of the WDK."

Comment: This seems really odd.  Does anyone have any idea of an alternate way to do this in version 1507 and later?  This feature is very helpful...

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2019, the shortcut **(while debugging and stopped at a breakpoint)** is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and now you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

The screenshot is pretty old. 
Here is one for Visual Studio 2019 (under the debug menu):

[image: Visual Studio 2019 Call Stack Menu Option]