# No stack trace on exception

Tags: visual-studio

I have .NET application that sometimes happily catches System.OutOfMemory (of unknown origin). I tried to debug it by attaching visual studio to it, but when exception happened, visual studio was unable to show me any stack trace. How can I get the stack trace?

Comment: When you catch it, it is too late to still get a stack trace.  Don't catch the Bad Stuff.  Btw, that call stack doesn't tell you anything interesting anyway.  An OOM can be raised anywhere.  You'll need a memory profiler to fix the leak.

Comment: Apparently, when you catch an exception, it's [not too late](https://stackoverflow.com/a/945597/712526) to get at the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to wrap any code that could result in an exception with a try-catch and then put a breakpoint on the catch statement of every try catch. So when you attach VS to it you will be able to analyse the Exception when the breakpoint has been triggered.

If you have a Main method wrap all the code in a try-catch and that might allow you to catch any exceptions that might be raised.