# How do I debug with stack trace in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, asp-classic

I wonder if it is possible to know the exact function or line of code in visual studio poses problem when we debugger returns an error page like this:

[image]

Because I can not find a function name in my existing code if I read the stack trace ..... Rather strange and very hard to debug unfortunately.
Thank you very much

Comment: I'm sure, but have you tried using `Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: '{0}'", Environment.StackTrace);`

Comment: What page is it on? What Telerik controls do you use on this page?

Comment: This link, may be helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945193/how-do-i-find-the-stack-trace-in-visual-studio

Comment: @Linguini no I have not tried. But I will add that bit of code everywhere! This may be a job that would take a lot of time ...

Comment: @Arran Many ^ ^ Radajaxmanager, radbutton, Radgrid, etc. ..
Why this question?

Comment: @Linguini Thanks a lotts ! its a great solution !! Do you can write this solution please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While debugging you can check the **Call Stack** to get the idea about the order for execution of the code.

By using the Call Stack window, you can view the function or procedure calls that are currently on the stack.

Check this for more details: [How to: Use the Call Stack Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[image]