# How to save a streamed document and use information on document in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

Hi Im currently working on my last assignment from a programming class and I'm pretty new to the area of programming. My assignment was to stream a document through Streamreader and extract the information for a menu program to access the document.

So far I have only been able to stream

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"\Users\changl\Desktop");

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("earthquakes.csv"))
            {
                String line;

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm rather in experienced in the programming and would like some help on what my next step is for saving the information in the document for later use.

Answer (score 1):

Console.Writeline just writes the information out to the console window you need some form of a way to save this..

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("earthquakes.csv"))
    {
        String line;
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
           // Console.WriteLine(line);
            myList.add(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Getting an Error saying "type or name space for List not found.

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic;

Answer (score 1):

You need to just split each line by `,`,`;`,`\t`:

```
var fieldsEnumerable = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
```

but [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86973/C-CSV-Reader-and-Writer) library will do it for you:

```
List<List<string>> records = new List<List<string>>();

using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(FilePath, Encoding.Default))
{
    while (reader.ReadNextRecord())
        records.Add(reader.Fields);
}
```

Comment: I've tried something like this before but I'm getting an error saying "Type or Name space for List not found."

Comment: first example updated, please try it. first look in your file and ensure the `, (comma)` has been separated each field.

Comment: Sorry but im completely new to this site and I have no idea how to post the whole code on here....Do I edit the original post?

Comment: yes , edit original post, and add your code and StackTrace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945193/how-do-i-find-the-stack-trace-in-visual-studio