# Stack Trace tab in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017

Tags: exception, resharper, visual-studio-2017, stack-trace

I am currently working on code that throws exceptions.
Sometime last week, I *accidentally* opened a tab along the bottom of Microsoft Visual Studio that contained all of the stack trace information that I can normally find while examining the exception, locating "Stack Trace" and clicking on the Magnifying Glass, which will open a new window that contains text with extra details about the exception, such as which calls lead up to the exception, and exactly which line of code threw the exception.

The most interesting thing about this Stack Trace tab is that it allowed me to *click* on the information and Microsoft Visual Studio would automatically show me the line within the file in question.

Most of the information that I find about this directs me to the Call Stack tab, which is not what I'm looking for. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945193/how-do-i-find-the-stack-trace-in-visual-studio) of a question that is worded similarly, but does not give the answer that I'm looking for.

I've tried finding the Stack Trace window using Resharper:

[image]

And this will open this Stack Trace window, that seems like it *should* be what I'm looking for, but it only shows a date value. This date might be related to the exception that I'm looking for, but I'm looking for the information within the window that I can find by inspecting the exception object. Here's a screenshot that shows that the Stack Trace Explorer window displays: [image]

**EDIT** *I just found out that this text comes directly from what is currently in my clipboard.*

Here is a screenshot that contains information that I'm looking for, but I'd like to find this information with clickable lines that allow me to navigate to the lines related to the exception. (I redacted potentially sensitive text within the screenshot. I included this screenshot only to give an idea about the information that I'm looking for.)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Something about the Stack Trace Explorer takes information from the clipboard when it is opened.

The information that is contained within the Stack Trace Magnifying Glass popup that is found by inspecting the contents of the Exception can be put into ReSharper's Stack Trace window by copying the entire contents of the Exception's Stack Trace information, then opening ReSharper's Stack Trace window.

Within this Stack Trace window, details can be clicked on to navigate to the target line within the target file.

I'm going to keep this question/answer available instead of deleting it, in case it will help somebody in the future.