# How do I get stack trace in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am getting Exceptions in the *Output* window of Visual Studio but do not know what code is causing these exceptions.  I would like to get a stack trace so I can properly debug them.

Here is a sample of the exceptions I am getting:

[image]

The one I am particularly interested in in the `NullReferenceException`.

I have looked at this SO post:
[How do I find the stack trace in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945193/how-do-i-find-the-stack-trace-in-visual-studio)
But my menu looks like this:

[image]

I tried to follow these instructions for adding the "Exceptions" choice to the Debug menu but all I can find it "Exceptions Settings":

[image]

Seeing a stack trace of an exceptions seems like such a common need I have a hard time believing that VS is hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a tabbed panel on the bottom of VS and was able to modify the Exceptions that cause VS to break on the "Exception Settings" tab.

[image]