# Throw System.StackOverflowException Error when I call my Data Model Context class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

**Data Model Context:**

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class ExampleEntities : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Example1> Example1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Example2> Example { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Example3> Example3 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Example4> Example4 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my Data Access Layer file when I try to initialize the context,

```
private ExampleEntities _context = new ExampleEntities();
```

> {"Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown."}
>   [image]

This exception thrown.

Comment: It would help if you provide the fully details, including message, stacktrace, etc. | But even with that, I can pretty confidentially say: Somewhere in that you either got a way to deep recursion - or even a infinite recursion. The stack in question is the function call stack.

Comment: Stack overflows occur under two conditions 1) You have an endless loop in the code.  For example if you recursively call the same method in a loop. 2) Your database is very large and you are loading lots of data.  I suspect you have the constructor for ExampleEntities calling the constructor a 2nd time.

Comment: The StackOverflowException is basically the nice way of telling you, that the **Operating System** took issue with that amount of recursion: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception#remarks | But it was not so critical that it had to outright *kill* your process - just cancel those functions. | @jdweng propably knows more about EF then I, so he knows the likely causes with EF.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945193/how-do-i-find-the-stack-trace-in-visual-studio#:~:targetText=To%20open%20the%20Call%20Stack,first%20column%20of%20the%20row.

Comment: I just have seen the overflow issue a lot of times when writing recursive methods.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks. You are right, My case is number 2. Please make an answer so that I can Accept it.