# SQLite error Insufficient parameters supplied to the command

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

When trying to change the active column in the following table [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvBkK.jpg).

I get the error

> Error insufficient parameters supplied to the command

and I cannot figure out for the life of me what is wrong with the code. Please help.

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SQLiteConnection sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection();
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "datasource = SubjectTable.db";

        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            ID = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

            //Define SELECT Statement
            string commandText = "SELECT * FROM SubjectTable WHERE ID=" + ID;

            //Create a datatable to save data in memory 
            var datatable = new DataTable();
            SQLiteDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(commandText, sqlConnection);

            sqlConnection.Open();

            //Fill data from database into datatable
            myDataAdapter.Fill(datatable);

            //Fill data from datatable into form controls
            CMBactive.Text = datatable.Rows[0]["Active"].ToString();
            TBsubjectBUD.Text = datatable.Rows[0]["Budget"].ToString();

            sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is causing the error? and, is this during Compile time or Run Time Execution?

Comment: if the value of `ID` is an empty string your query would fail. Set a breakpoint in the `var datatable...` line and check the value of `commandText`.

Comment: @JayV Its during the run time when I change the combo box and click confirm

Comment: @Cleptus ID is working and displaying the ID value of the selected subject :(

Comment: Unrelated: Do not concat your sql queries. Use query parameters.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of the exception (as _text_).

Comment: @Fildor going to be completley honest with you mate, im in year 11 and doing this for an assignment and idk what query parametres are or stacktrace

Comment: No problem. We got your a** covered: For Stacktrace see answeres here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/945193/982149. For query parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/q/809246/982149

Comment: @Fildor Legend thanks heaps!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting these problems, because you are trying to do too much things in one procedure. You should [separate your concerns](https://blog.ndepend.com/separation-of-concerns-explained/)

Separate the fetching of the data from the database from displaying this data; separate also that you do this of event selection changed.

This has the advantage that you can reuse your code more easily: if you want to do the same because of a Button press, you can reuse the code. After that it is a one-liner code if you want to add a menu item doing the same.

It is easier to test your code if you have a separate method to query the database, or a separate method to fill your controls CmbActive and TbSubjectBud.

It is easier to change your code, for instance, if you will not use SQLite anymore, but entity framework to fetch your data, the displaying and the button handling won't notice this. Only the procedure to fetch the data needs to be changed.

This makes unit testing easier: instead of a real database, you can mock the database with a Dictionary for the tests.

Finally: when using Winforms, don't fiddle with the Cells directly, use the DataSource of the DataGridView to fill and read the data. Again: separate the data from how it is displayed.

### First Your actual problem: query the data

So you have an Id, and you want to fetch the values of columns `Active` and `Budget` from all Subjects from the database that have this Id. Don't fetch properties that you won't use!

### Database handling

First we need a class Subject to put the data that you fetch from table `SubjectTable`. If you put all columns of this table in it, you can reuse the class for other queries. However. you don't have to fill in all fields. It depends how often you will call this method whether it is wise to fill all properties or only some.

Some people don't like this. Consider to fetch always all columns (inefficient), or to create classes for different queries (a lot of work).

```
class Subject
{
    public int Id {set; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}

    public string Active {get; set;}
    public Decimal Budget {get; set;}
}
```

Create a method to fetch the Active and Budget from tableSubjects with Id, or null if there is not subject with this Id.

Put all your database queries in a separate class. For instance class `Repository`. You hide that it is in a database, if in future you want to save it in a CSV-file, or JSON format, no one will notice (nice if you want to use it in a unit test!)

```
private Subject FetchBudgetOrDefault(int id)
{
    const string sqlText = @"SELECT Active, Budget FROM SubjectTable WHERE ID = @Id";
    using (var dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(this.dbConnectionString))
    {
         using (var dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand()
         {
             dbCommand.Commandtext = sqlText;
             dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
             using (var dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 if (dbReader.Read())
                 {
                     // There is a Subject with this id:
                     return new Subject()
                     {
                         Id = id,
                         Active = dbReader.GetString(0),
                         Budget = (decimal)dbReader.GetInt64(1) / 100.0D,
                     };
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      // no subject with this Id
                      return null;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

I assumed that the decimal `Budget` is saved as `long * 100` on purpose, to show you that by separating your concerns it is fairly easy to change the database layout without having to change all users: if you want to save this decimal in SQLite as a REAL, then the queries are the only place where you have to change the data.

**By the way: this method also solved your problem: ID can't be an empty string!**

If you won't do this query 1000 times a second, consider to fetch all columns of Subject. This is a bit less efficient, but easier to test, reuse, and maintain.

### Display the fetched data in your form

Currently you display the data in a ComboBox and a TextBox. If you separate your concerns, there will only be one place where you do this. If you want to display the data in a Table, or do something else with it, you only have to change one place:

```
public void Display(Subject subject)
{
    this.comboBoxActive.Text = subject.Active;
    this.textBoxBudget.Text = subject.Budget.ToString(...);
}
```

Bonus points: if you want to change the format of the displayed budget, you'll only have to do this here.

### Read and Write the DataGridView

It is seldom a good idea to read and write the cells of a DataGridView directly. It is way to much work. You'll have to do all type checking yourself. A lot of work to test and implement small changes in the displayed data.

It is way easier to use the DataSource.

In the DataSource of the DataGridView you put a sequence of similar items. If you only want to Display once, an `ICollection<TSource>` will be enough (Array, List). If you want to update changes automatically, use a `BindingList<TSource>`

In the DataGridView add columns. User property `DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName` to indicate which property should be displayed in that column.

Usually it is enough to use visual studio designer to add the columns.

If your datagridview displays Subjects, code will be like:

```
DataGridView dgv1 = new DataGridView();
DataGridViewColumn columnId = new DataGridViewColumn
{
    DataPropertyName = nameof(Subject.Id),
    ...
};
DataGridView columnName = new DataGridViewColumn
{
    DataPropertyName = nameof(Subject.Name),
    ...
};
... // other columns
dgv.Columns.Add(columnId);
dgv.Columns.Add(columnName);
...
```

In your forms class:

```
private BindingList<Subject> DisplayedSubjects {get; set;} = new BindingList<Subject>();

// Constructor:
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.dgv1.DataSource = this.DisplayedSubjects();
}
void FillDataGridView()
{

    using (var repository = new Repository())
    {
        IEnumerable<Subject> fetchedSubjects = repository.FetchAllSubjects();
        this.DisplayedSubjects = new BindingList<Subject>(fetchedSubjects.ToList();

    }
}
```

This is all that is needed to display all fetched subjects. If the operator changes any cell value, the corresponding value in `this.DislayedSubjects` is automatically updated.
This works both ways: if you change any value in `this.DisplayedSubjects`, the displayed value in the DataGridView is automatically updated.

No need to read the cells directly. If you allow column reordering, or if you implement row sorting, then everything still works two ways. Because you separated the fetched data from the displayed data, you can change the display without having to change the fetched data.

### Put it all together

When you get the event that the selection is changed from the datagridview you want to update Active and Budget. Let's do the from the Selected item:

```
void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, EventHandler e)
{
    // Get the selected Subject
    var selectedSubject = this.SelectedSubject;
    this.Display(selectedSubject); // described above
}

Subject SelectedSubject => this.Dgv.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                               .Select(row => (Subject)row.DataBoundItem)
                               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Because you separated concerns, each method is easy to understance, easy to test, easy to reuse and to change slightly: if you want to update after a Button Press or a menu item, the code will be a one liner. If you want to display other items than just Active / Budget: small changes; if you want to fetch by Name instead of Id: only limited changes needed.